# PhpStorm doesn't transfer files via SFTP deployment

Tags: php, deployment, virtual-machine, phpstorm, sftp

I have a strange problem. For a long time I used to deploy my files from local macbook to local VM via SFTP deployment by PhpStorm. From one moment, without doing any configuration changes (as far as I recognized) it does't work any more.

- When I hit the `Test SFTP connection` button in the settings it tells me that it was successful.
- When I click `Tools -> Deployment -> Browse remote server` it seems to connect but doesn't show any files.
- When I right click a file and choose "upload to xy" it says `[13.02.15 20:15] Upload to xy` but the file never shows up on the VM.

In VM auth.log appears:

> Feb 13 20:15:39 precise64 sshd[2272]: Connection closed by 33.33.33.1 [preauth]

**What I did so far:**

- Update PhpStorm to 8.0.3.
- Update Java to 1.8.0_31.
- Update ssh to 6.7p1.
- Invalidate Caches and Restart PhpStorm.

Don't know what to do else. Vagrant ssh and ssh or scp with credentials from my PhpStorm works fine on command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, OK... found out how to use PhpStorm debugging and I guess thats the problem. But how to fix it?

2015-02-13 20:38:49,618 [1473684]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b

Answer (score 0):

Why is it always searching for hours and as far as you post it somewhere you find the answer yourself?

I came across this site: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks It says that JDK 1.6 should be used. I reinstalled it and tadaaa it works.